# Is this url verification with startsWith secure?

Tags: android, java, url, webview

I would like to know if this code is secure to validate that a url is from my domain before loading it a webview in android :

```
if (!url.startsWith("https://www.example.com/test/")){
   // don't load the url
   dontload = true;
}
```

It looks secure but do you know if there is any way to bypass it ? Maybe with URL encoding ?

I use this code in onPreExecute to set the boolean that is checked before loading the url.

I get the url from `url = getIntent().getDataString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such check is safe.

A similar check might be error prone. For instance, if you used

```
url.startsWith("https://www.example.com")
```

it could give an unexpected result, if you had a URL like

```
https://www.example.com@www.google.com
```

The part before `@` would be interpreted as a user+password. But it user+password cannot contain unescaped `/`. The URL you test includes `/` (...com/...), thus your against such attacks.

I don't see any weaknesses in your check.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that too but just wanted to be sure ! Thanks !